Reconciling metric and topological neighborhoods
Let $X$ be a metric space. Given a point in $x \in X$, an open neighborhood is more appropriately called an $\epsilon$-ball $N_\epsilon = \{p \in X : d(p, x) < \epsilon\}$, while a topological neighborhood is any open set containing $x$. I am wondering if there is a rigorous way to reconcile these definitions, based on the facts that open sets are unions of open balls. One example is in the definition of limit points: $p$ is a limit point of a subset $E \subseteq X$ iff for all open subsets $G \subseteq X$ such that $p \in G$, $E \cap (G - \{x\}) \ne \emptyset$. But can the definitions be used interchangeably in arbitrary formulas? If so, how to formulate this?

The balls are, by definition, a basis for the topology, so yes, in practice either can be used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)


Given a point in $x\in X$, an open neighborhood is more appropriately called an $\epsilon$-ball ...

That's not how I read the definition, e.g. Wikipedia's (in the "In a metric space" section). A neighborhood of a point must contain an $\epsilon$-ball around the point - it doesn't have to be an $\epsilon$-ball centered on the point. And a set is said to be open if it is a neighborhood for all the points out contains.
I don't see any contradiction that needs reconciling. Can you be more specific - is there a contradiction you still see, if you use this definition of neighborhood?

The two definitions are taken from Rudin PMA and Munkres Topology. I'm not saying there is any contradiction at all, just wondering if there's a way for these to be seamlessly swapped in theorems. I think Qiaochu Yuan's comment on bases was really helpful.
